# How to Execute an activity N times ,Where N is user input

Tags: java, android

I wanted to execute a particular activity or a fragment which takes data and save it to database,and that activity executes N number of times. Here N(integer) is the given input from the user

If A is an activity which executes activity B multiple time or N number of times, where N is the given input from the user.where activity B takes some user input data and saves in database N number of times.

Eg:
Activity A ---> Enter the number of questions  _____(8)
                   Button[next]--Executes activity B

Activity B----> Enter the 1st Question ______________________________
                 Button[Next]
                           When i click Next button, it  should save the first question and must repeat activity B 8 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide a startActivity method with a parameter N for activity B, and use it to pass N from activity A to B, on click of the next button goto activity B again if N is greater than zero and finish current activity to avoid memory leaks and minus N by one each time, this should work, here is some kotlin code

```
class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun start(context: Context, n: Int) {
            val intent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("N", n)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        lateinit var n: Int

        .
        .
        .

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            ...
            n = intent.getIntExtra("N", 0)

            nextButton.setOnClickListener {
                if( n > 0 ) {
                    ActivityB.startActivity(this, n-1)
                } else {
                    // do what you need to do
                }
                activity?.finish()
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: yaa It works ,Thank you . But i wanted to do this with java

Comment: upvote and accept the answer then, it can be easily converted to java, use android studio decompiler

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want a For loop. Without knowing what code you have, I can only provide psuedo-code.

```
int userInput = getUserInput();

for(i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
    // Display the form
    // User inputs data
    // Write it to the database
}
```

Comment: I would like to mention one point. I guess he should pass userInput from Activity A to Activity B. I guess they are different classes which A gets input, and B saves data to db.

Comment: Please make your widgets appropriately and then use appropriate patterns. You should not be creating the widgets so many times. You should try reusing the same. Activity creation and deletion is expensive try avoiding it.